# how to resize grid tiles based on window size within a range

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

Essentially, i'm trying to figure out how to copy the effect on this page

https://music.twitter.com/i/chart/popular

As the window is resized, javascript is used to resize the grid tiles from between 200 and 240px based on which would fill the screen best.

At the risk of reinventing the wheel, is there a javascript / jquery library that already does this? It's along the same lines as masonry / isotope but they don't resize the elements as far as I know.

If not, I guess i'll just have a go at it myself, it doesn't sound too complicated in theory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so i've taken a look at the site and off the top of my head - I do not know of any plugins / libraries that accomplish specifically that effect.   is there a particular benefit you gain or specific requirement to achieving this effect with jQuery?  if not i would strongly recommend the css3 responsive design approach utilizing media queries.

[**check out this fiddle for a quick example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tCJbF/) of what i was able to do with a small amount of just html and css

```
.icon {
    background:#ccc;
    float:left;
}

.icon img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width:960px)  {
    .icon{
        width:20%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:959px) {
    .icon{
        width:25%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:767px) {
    .icon{
        width:33.3%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:479px) {
    .icon{
        width:50%;
    }
}
```

from my experience specific to problems similar to yours, media queries turn out to be more lightweight than performing similar actions in javascript, both referring to intensity of resource usage as well as amount work.

if you are unfamiliar with media queries - [***THIS article on the mozilla developer network is a great starting point***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Thanks Joe, I think I was having trouble seeing the wood for the trees. I had looked at media queries but the penny hadn't dropped that I could do one query for each number of columns where percentage width is 100/no. of columns. Thanks so much!